# Can I use a Node TCP socket in a C++ extension?

Tags: c++, node.js, libuv

I have a C++ Node.js extension that does network communication. Currently, it creates its own TCP connections in C. I would like to have it use sockets created in Node to take advantage of standard libraries like [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) and to be able to use the existing event loop.

The solution I see is to simply create a [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) object and then extract the `uv_tcp_t` value from the underlying `TCPWrap` object. There are a couple of issues I see with this option:

1. The Socket documentation seems to indicate that a socket immediately starts reading when it connects. I would expect that to cause data loss if I want to read on the underlying UV socket in the extension instead of listening for the 'data' event in JavaScript.
2. While the TCPWrap class has a function to get the underlying `uv_tcp_t` struct, it does not seem to have an API to relinquish ownership of that struct. I expect this to cause problems later related to disposing of the struct and ownership of its `data` member (used for user data).

Is there any way to avoid these issues and use the socket in the extension?